# Entity Framework 5 replaces delete+insert with update

Tags: entity-framework-5

Simply put, I'm trying to update a list of related entities; they have composite primary keys and an additional constraint (a sort of ordinal column should be unique, something like RowNumber). Now, when making more complex edits to the collection, I can't just issue updates to each row because the constraint will be violated - reordering two entities with consecutive RowNumbers, for example (let's put aside the validity of that constraint for now, that's not the point).

So I thought, well in this case it's easy, I'll just delete the entities and recreate them. Except that EF seems to detect that the same entity is inserted after it's deleted (based on its primary key which stays the same), so it transforms the delete+insert into an update. At least that's what I'm seeing with the profiler after making absolutely certain the old and new entities are in the deleted and added states, respectively.

Normally I'd say that's a pretty logical thing to do but... Is there any way to alter this behavior? Is this really what's happening or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you call save changes after the delete, then add the new record?

Comment: Well no, I do realize that would be the easy option but I'm trying to do things generically instead of writing the same code for each similar entity I'll work with... It could work but it'll complicate the code quite a bit, it would need to be wrapped in a transaction and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I was forced to assume this is indeed what's happening, and it sort of makes sense as an optimization... sort of. I changed my DB model to always use surrogate keys (that's what EF works best with anyway) and this prevents it identifying the deleted and inserted entities as being the exact same thing, which means the delete+insert is not replaced with an update. I suppose that's not too bad, even if it does mean the surrogate key will keep increasing with each such edit.